# Shell Script Invocation Error - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, build, exit-code

I've recently picked up a project from another developer, who couldn't complete the project. The only problem I have, is that I can't get the project to build for the simulator, or for a device, through Xcode.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Failed to write out copy of document for diagnostics: Failed to write copy of document to path "(null)": Failed to write out copy of document because it has no file URL
Showing first 200 notices only

**Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255**
```

Could anyone advise as to where to start looking to de-bug this build issue?

**Extra details:**
I'm running Xcode 6.0.1. In the 'Run Script' area of the 'Build Phases', there is a Shell (/bin/sh) script for Crashlytics.framework, which I haven't previously used.. Not sure if that helps.

**EDIT**

There are two Shells in the build phases. Crashlytics and pods:

```
Shell: /bin/sh

"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"
```

and

```
Shell: /bin/sh

./Crashlytics.framework/run xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Which of the two scripts caused the error ?

Comment: @KudoCC - This is the problem. I don't know. I'd suggest is wasn't the pods, as I have removed and re-installed them.

Comment: i'm facing exactly the same problem and i need help on it

Comment: Try this [ERROR CODE 255](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997378/4344659) its a complete description how you resole your issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution** - This error was caused by the new version of Xcode (6), trying to convert xibs and used in some of the pods used in the project.

Solution 1 - Re-download Xcode 5.1 from the member centre: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Solution 2 - Update Pods, linked files and current code base to meet iOS 8 standards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem it is solved. One of my pods (in my case was ICETutorial) were casing problems because of its xib files. When I removed this pod the app worked fine. Also you may need to uninstall pods and install them again; also update them for iOS8 support.

Try to check each pod in your app; I guess one of them casing this problem.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: @mac10688 CocoaPods is a dependency manager and pods are like packages. refer to https://cocoapods.org/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I found that carthage was not installed. Installed carthage through brew then did a rebuild. This time got a message to setup Fabric because it was used by the original developer. Installed Fabric and followed their instructions. The problem is gone. Hope this helps.