# Flutter - iOS: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, flutter

Good afternoon,

I try to run a Flutter project on iOS, previously successfully run on Android. However, I got an error:

```
"x86_64" is not an allowed value for option "ios-arch".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
Failed to build /Users/user123/Downloads/my_app.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255
```

I tried different solutions offered here about a variety of errors "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code XXX". But, none of them helped.

Also, I checked solutions on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9814.
At the same time, it is not completely clear for me how to implement them into iOS project.

I will be appreciated for any support.

Sincerely,
Maryna

Update: these are the results of the commands:

```
$ flutter run --verbose
[  +53 ms] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +60 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/beta
[        ] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] beta
[        ] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 5ab9e70727d858def3a586db7fb98ee580352957
[        ] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 3 weeks ago
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v0.8.2-0-g5ab9e7072
[ +508 ms] executing: /Users/user143726/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +32 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/user143726/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
[   +8 ms] executing: idevice_id -h
[  +98 ms] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list --json devices
[ +449 ms] No connected devices.
[        ] Run 'flutter emulators' to list and start any available device emulators.
[        ] If you expected your device to be detected, please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose
[        ] potential issues, or visit https://flutter.io/setup/ for troubleshooting tips.
[  +18 ms] "flutter run" took 1,014ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand 
(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:239:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand 
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:350:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:306:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:297:20)
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:347:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:303:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:29)
#21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:11)
#23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:211:18)
#24     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:59:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#28     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#29     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#30     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:42:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#33     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:52:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#34     main     (file:///b/build/slave/Mac_Flutter_Packaging/build/archive/flutter/packages/fl    utter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#35     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure>     (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#36     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)

$ flutter analyze
Analyzing my_app...                                          

info • Unused import: 'package:my_app/main.dart' • test/widget_test.dart:10:8 • unused_import

1 issue found. (ran in 8.4s)
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en)
• Flutter version 0.8.2 at /Users/user143726/Downloads/flutter
• Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (3 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
• Engine revision 58a1894a1c
• Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/user143726/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
• ios-deploy 2.0.0
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 28.0.1
• Dart plugin version 173.4700
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[!] VS Code (version 1.27.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension not installed; install from
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected devices
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: please run `flutter run --verbose`, `flutter analyze` and `flutter doctor -v` and paste the results in your question...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @RicardoBRGWeb! I have updated initial question with results of the commands.

Comment: I have had this problem before, and my quickest solution is to restart a blank project and copy all the dart code to the new project. That works for some reason.

Comment: @MarySeleznova there are no devices nor emulators available. Did you try starting iOS simulator and then running on it? Also try to run `flutter clean` to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @dshukertjr, thanks a lot for your comment! Have you done this in Android Studio? or in Xcode?

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb, it is quite strange, but I am running iPhone X in the emulator. I even changed the device in the emulator but it still is not shown in flutter doctor

Comment: @MarySeleznova I tried building my app in X code and it did not work. This happened to me multiple times, and every time I end up creating a whole new project.

Comment: @dshukertjr, please, forgive me my entry level of knowledge in this field, but, how did you put the Dart code into Xcode project? I have just googled this topic but also nothing helpful...

Comment: @MarySeleznova Sorry, the way I said it might have been confusing. I was using VS Code, and when I run the app in VS Code, it automatically does the X Code build. What I did was just build my app through VS Code.

Comment: @dshukertjr one more thanks! I will try this method now

Comment: @MarySeleznova Hope it works!

Comment: @MarySeleznova Did it work for you, I'm encountering the same error and I'm in no state to create a new project for it.

Answer (score 8):

After lots of try i follow these steps to release ipa file :

1. Go to your trminal:
2. cd your-flutter-project
3. flutter run  (That will launch the app to your connected or opened device )

Now,
come to again to your MAC terminal and type

- flutter build apk (that will make the release apk)

For IOS,

- flutter build ios

after complete the task you will see the path of your file package something like

/Users/Sanjeev/Documents/WorkSpaceForFlutter/myapp/build/ios/iph
oneos/Runner.app.

Now go to Xcode >Product >Archive  you will get the screen below
[image]

This is how i resolve my issue 
**Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255**

Answer (score 5):

I solve the problem with the following commands.

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

After that I can create signed builds and also upload to App Stores.

Answer (score 2):

This exit code (255) occurs from incorrectly Generated.xcconfig configuration like TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION, FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR, FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE
In archive ios release mode. So before archiving make sure to run `flutter clean` then `flutter build ios` for some reason `flutter build ios --release` doesn't work for me. Then lastly go to Xcode and archive the ios app

Commands

`flutter clean` then

`flutter build ios`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me after building a release version. It seems that iOS emulators does not support release versions.

If you want to run your app on an emulator you will need to build a debug version

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happenned that I was opening `.xcodeproj (WRONG)` file instead of `.xcworkspace (RIGHT)`

Answer (score 0):

For me helped:

1. Disconnect all physical phone's from mac.
2. Close Xcode.
3. In terminal command

   flutter clean
4. Start Xcode by running Runner.xcworkspace, that you have inside your project folder /yourProjectFolder/ios/Runner

[image]

5. Choose menu Product - Archive

[image]

6. That's it! After that build was successful. Appear windows where you can distribute app.

[image]